# Stop searching for a string if found while using forfiles command

Tags: batch-file, findstr, forfiles

I wrote a simple batch file that search for a specific string.

```
forfiles /S /M TraceLog-* /d +%SearchDate% /c "cmd /c findstr /c:\"Not enough disk space to save focus debug data.\" @path" >> %FileName%
```

Is there a way to stop the run so the output file will contain only a **single** message of "Not enough disk space to save focus debug data".
That means - if the above string was found - stop the loop.

Comment: It is not possible to abort the `forfiles` loop upon a certain condition (without aborting its process in a quite complex way). Anyway, instead of `>> %FileName%`, redirect to a temporary file like `> "%FileName%.tmp"`, then read its first line of this file using `< "%FileName%.tmp" (set "LINE=" & set /P LINE="")` and append it to the log file by `del "%FileName%.tmp" & echo/%LINE%>> "%FileName%"` (`del` cleans up the temporary file)…

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I didn't understand the code you wrote for reading the first list. Can you please re-write it?

Comment: Type `set /?` and read the usage info; you'll find out that `set /P` is intended for user prompts; together with input redirection (`<`) you can read the entered text from a file instead; `set /P` only reads everything up to the first line-break...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`forfiles` command](https://ss64.com/nt/forfiles.html) does not provide a feature to terminate the loop once a certain condition is fulfilled.

However, you could instead let the loop finish but write its output to a temporary file, whose first line you copy into the target log file afterwards:

```cmd
rem // Do the loop but write output into a temporary file:
forfiles /S /M "TraceLog-*" /D +%SearchDate% /C "cmd /D /C findstr /C:\"Not enough disk space to save focus debug data.\" @path" > "%FileName%.tmp"
rem // Read the first line from the temporary file and store it in variable `LINE`:
< "%FileName%.tmp" (set "LINE=" & set /P LINE="")
rem // Append the read first line to the target log file:
if defined LINE echo(%LINE%>> "%FileName%"
rem // Eventually clean up the temporary file:
del "%FileName%.tmp"
```

This code (mis-)uses [`set /P`](https://ss64.com/nt/set.html) intended to prompt a value from the user for reading the first line of a file in combination with [input redirection `<`](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html).

Comment: Is there a way that forfiles command will support one date format?
It seems that for every local time zone i should use a different format
for example: SET SearchDate=%DD%-%MM%-%YYYY%  - for my time zone

Comment: I'm afraid no; `forfiles` expects the date delivered depending on the current locale settings...